# ¿Cómo se pronunciaban infinitivos ligados a pronombres con doble ele?

Tags: pronombres, pronunciación, infinitivo, español-medieval

En [el *Quijote*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2000/2000-h/2000-h.htm) hay varios ejemplos de infinitivos ligados a pronombres con doble ele:

> ...jurando de ir a buscar al valeroso don Quijote de la Mancha y **contalle** punto por punto lo que había pasado...
>
> ...bebieron del agua del arroyo de los batanes, sin volver la cara a **mirallos**...

Aunque noto que su uso no es exclusivo pues “contarle” y “mirarlos” también existen en el texto.

¿Cómo era la pronunciación de estas palabras en esa época? A mis oídos suena extraño utilizar el sonido de “-ll-” y me pregunto si posiblemente se pronunciaban igual que las versiones con “-rl-” o con dos eles separadas como “-l·l-” en catalán ([ele geminada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C2%B7l)).

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a nuestro sitio, Ian! Debo decir que tu primera pregunta ha sido buenísima, mira que habré visto veces esas construcciones de infinitivo y nunca me había parado a cuestionarme esto. Espero que te hayan gustado las respuestas, y que sigas viniendo a hacernos todas las preguntas que quieras.

Answer (score 8):

Cuando leíamos el Quijote hace un par de años en un grupo de Twitter surgió este asunto y yo pensé inicialmente que se trataba de una /l/ doble o geminada, como la del catalán (más allá de que introdujera una ambigüedad en la escritura), porque habría sido de lo más natural asimilar /rl/ a /ll/ y porque de hecho esta asimilación ocurre hoy en día en algunos dialectos.

Una estudiosa de la literatura del Siglo de Oro que seguía la lectura me aclaró que no era así, sino que efectivamente se pronunciaba una *elle* (fuera de que no hay manera de saber si era una aproximante palatal lateral o una fricativa como suele ser hoy). Lo que demuestra el hecho es que cuando ocurre este grupo en poesía rimada consonante, el mismo rima regularmente con instancias conocidas de *elle*. No recuerdo un ejemplo, pero digamos que *amalle* (de *amarle*) rimaría con *calle* y *buscalla* (de *buscarla*) rimaría con *batalla*, y así.

Answer (score 3):

Recuerdo en la obra de teatro "La venganza de Don Mendo" que lo pronunciaban como 'll':

Quedad con él y exhortalle,
 fray Luis de Jerusalén;
 confesalle y preparalle
 para bien morir, amén.